# The closed form for the integral: $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{2a}\arctan{x}}{x^2+1}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to find a closed form for this integral:
$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{2a}\arctan{x}}{x^2+1}dx$$

Where $a$ is any constant $\in R$. I use this approach, but still don't get the result:

First, use the series of $\arctan{x}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}x^{2k+1}$ then $$I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{2a}\arctan{x}}{x^2+1}dx=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{2a+2k+1}}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\left(H_{\frac{a+k}{2}}-H_{\frac{1}{2} (a+k-1)}\right)$$

But I got stuck at this step. Can you give me some hints, or another approaches? Thank you so much.

Comment: Perhaps this can help:  If $a=1$, $I = -\frac{1}{32} (\pi -8) \pi -\frac{\log (2)}{2}$ and if $a=2$, $I = \frac{1}{96} (-16+\pi  (3 \pi -16)+64 \log (2))$

Comment: Mathematica cannot find a closed form. Rip

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible to find a closed form for an arbitrary a real.

One idea that can simplify things is to notice that

$(tan^{-1}(x))'=\dfrac{1}{1+x^{2}}$. Therefore we can write

$\int_{0}^{1}x^{2a}tan^{-1}(x)d(tan^{-1}(x))=\int_{0}^{\pi/4}(tany)^{2a}ydy$

which e.g. for $a=1$ gives[image]

but I think it is very unlikely to have a closed form for any $a$.

I hope that would be of some help!!